# Text-based RPG in C++

Tags: c++, role-playing-game

It is currently unfinished; only `case 1` of the `switch(hunt)` is available for choosing.

Please give detailed feedback and/or quality explanations on improvements or fixes; I'm brand new to C++ and don't know a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int warrior, mage, rogue, priest;
    int class1, classID;
    int HP, mana, manaCost, attack, abilitydmg;
    int hpPots, manaPots, potionInv; 
    hpPots = 0;
    manaPots = 0;
    std::string abilityname;

    std::cout   << "                          --Choose a Class--\n\n"
                 "---[1] Warrior---\n"
                 "The warrior uses mighty attacks and has a unique stun ability.\n\n"
                 "---[2] Mage---\n"
                 "The mage uses the arcane arts to fire magical bolts from his fingertips.\n\n"
                 "---[3] Rogue---\n"
                 "The rogue uses the arts of assasination and uses a powerful backstab move.\n\n"
                 "---[4] Priest---\n"
                 "The priest uses the holy arts and has a heal ability.\n";

    std::cin    >> class1;

        switch(class1)
        {
            case 1:
                classID=1;
                std::cout   << "\nEquipped Rusty Sword!\n"
                            "+7 Attack!\n"
                            "Learned Slam!\n";
                            attack = 7;
                            abilitydmg = 8;
                            abilityname = "Slam";
                            manaCost = 20;
                std::cin.get();
                break;


            case 2:
                classID=2;
                std::cout   << "\nEquipped Wooden Staff!\n"
                            "+2 Attack\n"
                            "Learned Arcane Bolt!\n";
                            attack = 2; 
                            abilitydmg = 8;
                            abilityname = "Arcane Bolt"; 
                            manaCost = 15;
                std::cin.get();
                break;


            case 3:
                classID=3;
                std::cout   << "\nEquipped Broken Dagger!\n"
                            "+5 Attack!\n"
                            "Learned Backstab!\n";
                            attack = 5; 
                            abilitydmg = 30;
                            abilityname = "Backstab"; 
                            manaCost = 50;
                std::cin.get();
                break;


            case 4:
                classID=4;
                std::cout   << "\nEquipped Old Mace!\n"
                            "+5 Attack!\n"
                            "Learned Heal!\n";  
                            attack = 5;
                            abilitydmg = 10;
                            abilityname = "Heal";
                            manaCost = 10;
                std::cin.get();
                break;
        }
    tavern:
    int hunt;
    HP=100; 
    mana=100;

        std::cout   << "\n\nYou sit at the dim tavern, finishing a pint of ale.\n"
                    "The bitter taste coats the inside of your mouth.\n"
                    "You can hear the rowdy crowd behind you.\n"
                    "You pay the bartender.\n";
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout   << "\n--------------------------\n\n"
                    "You see the owner post new hunts on the bounty board. You approach it\n"
                    "and read the following:\n\n"
                    "Need a strong and witful bounty hunter to rid of Farm Giant destroying\n"
                    "crops and terrorizing town. Will pay in gold\n\n"
                    "Which bounty do you take?\n"
                    "[1] Farm Giant\n";
        std::cin    >> hunt;
        std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";





    switch(hunt)
    {
    case 1:
            int trail, caveEnter;
            int fight1, fight2, giantFight, action1, action2, action3, riddleAnswer;
            int loot;
            int goblinAttack, goblinHP, giantAction;
                goblinAttack = 5;
                goblinHP = 10;
            int skeletonAttack, skeletonHP;
                skeletonAttack = 3;
                skeletonHP = 15;
            int giantAttack, giantHP;
                giantAttack = 15;
                giantHP = 50; 

        std::cout   << "You head down the northern trail that leads to the meadow.\n"
                    "Villagers are spotted carrying their belongings and moving the\n"
                    "opposite direction of the meadow. You hear whispers of the giant\n"
                    "from the oncoming villagers.\n\n";
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                    "As you reach the edge of the road, you come across two more trails.\n\n"
                    "One trail leads into a valley. Cliffs stand tall on both sides. It looks\n"
                    "daunting, but dooable\n"
                    "The other path runs across the side of a dirty river. The pathway leads\n"
                    "down a hill, diverging at the end of a solemn graveyard.\n\n"
                    "You recall both trails lead to the meadow eventually.\n\n"
                    "Which do you take?\n"
                    "[1] Valley Trail\n"
                    "[2] River Trail\n"
                    "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
        std::cin    >> trail; 


        if(trail==1)
        {
            std::cout   << "As you head down the valley you notice large spires\n"
                        "made of jagged stone tower over you. Halfway down the path\n"
                        "you spot a cave. The entrance is just narrow enough for you\n"
                        "to fit in.\n"
                        "Do you enter the cave or move on?\n"
                        "[1] Enter\n"
                        "[2] Move on\n"
                        "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
            std::cin    >> caveEnter;



            if(caveEnter==1)
            {   
                std::cout   << "You croutch as you approach the entrance. Water drips\n"
                            "deep in the cave, splashing into a larger puddle. Sunlight peers\n"
                            "through a sky light in a large opening a couple feet in front of the\n"
                            "entrance. At the other side of the room lies an old chest.\n\n"
                            "Before you can react a goblin leaps off a nearby ledge in front of you\n";
                std::cin.get();
                std::cout   << "Do you fight or flee?\n\n"
                            "[1] Fight\n"
                            "[2] Flee\n"
                            "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
                std::cin    >> fight1;


                    if(fight1==1)
                    {
                        goblinFight:
                        loot = rand() % 3 + 1; 
                        srand(time(NULL));

                        std::cout   << "\nYour HP: "    << HP << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Your Mana: " << mana << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Your Attack: " << attack << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "\nEnemy HP: " << goblinHP << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Enemy Attack: " << goblinAttack << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "\nWhat do you do?\n"
                                    "[1] Attack            [2] " << abilityname << " (" << manaCost << " Mana)" << " (" << abilitydmg << " Damage)" << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "[3] Health Potion " << "(" << hpPots << ") " << "[4] Mana Potion " << "(" << manaPots << ")" << std::endl;
                        std::cin    >> action1;
                        std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

                        if(goblinHP<=0)
                        {
                            std::cout   << "You have slain the goblin!\n"
                                        "You head towards the chest and take the spoils\n"
                                        "of battle!\n\n";
                                switch(loot)
                            {
                                case 1: std::cout   << "---You find 1 Health Potion!---\n\n";
                                                    hpPots = hpPots + 1;
                                                    goto endTrail;
                                case 2: std::cout   << "---You find 1 Mana Potion!---\n\n";
                                                    manaPots = manaPots + 1;
                                                    goto endTrail;
                                case 3: std::cout   << "---You find 1 Health Potion and 1 Mana Potion!---\n\n";
                                                    manaPots = manaPots + 1;
                                                    hpPots = hpPots + 1;
                                                    goto endTrail;
                            }
                        }
                            if(HP<=1)
                            {
                                std::cout   << "\n\n---------- You have died! ----------\n\n";
                                std::cin.get();
                                            goto tavern;
                            }
                            else if(mana<=0)
                            {
                                std::cout << "You do not have enough Mana! You attack instead.\n";
                            }
                            if(action1==1)
                            {
                                std::cout   << "You successfully hit the goblin for " << attack << std::endl;
                                std::cout   << "He strikes back for " << goblinAttack << std::endl;
                                goblinHP = goblinHP - attack;
                                HP = HP - goblinAttack;
                                goto goblinFight;
                            }
                            else if(action1==2)
                            {
                                if(mana<=0)
                            {
                                std::cout << "\nYou do not have enough Mana!\n";
                                goto goblinFight;
                            }
                                if(classID==1)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You successfully stun the enemy and attack it for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                    goblinHP = goblinHP - abilitydmg;
                                    mana = mana - manaCost;
                                    goto goblinFight;
                                }
                                if(classID==4)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "The Holy Light infuses you. You successfully heal for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                    HP = HP + abilitydmg;
                                    mana = mana - manaCost;
                                    goto goblinFight;
                                }
                                else
                                std::cout   << "You successfully hit the goblin for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                std::cout   << "It strikes back for " << goblinAttack << std::endl;
                                goblinHP = goblinHP - abilitydmg;
                                HP = HP - goblinAttack;
                                mana = mana - manaCost;
                                goto goblinFight;
                            }
                            else if(action1==3) 
                            {
                                if(hpPots<=0)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You have no potions!\n\n";
                                    goto goblinFight;
                                }
                                else
                                std::cout   << "You drink the potion.\n"
                                            "+10 Health!";
                                HP = HP + 10;
                                hpPots = hpPots - 1;
                                goto goblinFight;
                            }
                            else if(action1==4) 
                            {
                                if(manaPots<=0)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You have no potions!\n\n";
                                    goto goblinFight;
                                }
                                else
                                std::cout   << "You drink the potion.\n"
                                            "+10 Mana!";
                                mana = mana + 10;
                                manaPots = manaPots - 1;
                                goto goblinFight;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                std::cout   << "You take the cowards way out and leave the cave.\n";
                                goto endTrail;
                            }                       
                        }
                    }
        }
    if(trail==2)
    {
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout   << "You head down the sloped hill that leads down to the river\n"
                    "The water is thick and murky as you examine it. A rotten\n"
                    "smell plagues the air.\n\n";
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                    "Continuing down the trail, the wretched smell worsens. It is almost\n"
                    "unbearable. The path starts to wind down a hill straight the the graveyard.\n"
                    "You feel an eerie presence surround you.\n\n"
                    "A skeleton emerges from a nearby grave!\n\n";
        std::cin.get();
        std::cout   << "What do you do?\n"
                    "[1] Fight\n"
                    "[2] Flee\n"
                    << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
        std::cin    >> fight2;


                    if(fight2==1)
                    {
                        skeletonFight:
                        loot = rand() % 3 + 1; 
                        srand(time(NULL));

                        std::cout   << "\nYour HP: "    << HP << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Your Mana: " << mana << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Your Attack: " << attack << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "\nEnemy HP: " << skeletonHP << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Enemy Attack: " << skeletonAttack   << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "\nWhat do you do?\n"
                                    << "[1] Attack            [2] " << abilityname << " (" << manaCost << " Mana)" << " (" << abilitydmg << " Damage)" << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "[3] Health Potion " << "(" << hpPots << ") " << "[4] Mana Potion " << "(" << manaPots << ")" << std::endl;
                        std::cin    >> action2;
                        std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
                    }
                        if(skeletonHP<=0)
                        {
                            std::cout   << "You have slain the skeleton!\n"
                                        "You scower his remains and take what you find useful.\n\n";
                            std::cin.get();
                            switch(loot)
                            {
                                case 1: std::cout   << "---You find 1 Health Potion!---\n\n";                           
                                                    hpPots = hpPots + 1;
                                                    goto endTrail;
                                case 2: std::cout   << "---You find 1 Mana Potion!---\n\n";
                                                    manaPots = manaPots + 1;
                                                    goto endTrail;
                                case 3: std::cout   << "---You find 1 Health Potion and 1 Mana Potion!---\n\n";
                                                    manaPots = manaPots + 1;
                                                    hpPots = hpPots + 1;
                                                    goto endTrail;
                            }
                        }   
                            if(HP<=0)
                            {
                                std::cout   << "\n\n---------- You have died! ----------\n\n";
                                std::cin.get();
                                            goto tavern;
                            }
                            else if(mana<=0)
                            {
                                std::cout << "You do not have enough Mana! You attack instead.\n";
                                goto skeletonFight;
                            }
                            if(action2==1)
                            {                               
                                std::cout   << "You successfully hit the skeleton for " << attack << std::endl;
                                std::cout   << "He strikes back for " << skeletonAttack << std::endl;
                                skeletonHP = skeletonHP - attack;
                                HP = HP - skeletonAttack;
                                goto skeletonFight;
                            }

                            if(action2==2)
                            {
                                if(mana<=0)
                            {
                                std::cout << "\nYou do not have enough Mana!\n";
                                goto skeletonFight;
                            }
                            if(classID==1)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You successfully stun the enemy and attack it for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                    skeletonHP = skeletonHP - abilitydmg;
                                    mana = mana - manaCost;
                                    goto skeletonFight;
                                }
                            if(classID==4)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "The Holy Light infuses you. You successfully heal for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                    HP = HP + abilitydmg;
                                    mana = mana - manaCost;
                                    goto skeletonFight;
                                }
                            else
                                std::cout   << "You successfully hit the skeleton for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                std::cout   << "It strikes back for " << skeletonAttack << std::endl;
                                skeletonHP = skeletonHP - abilitydmg;
                                HP = HP - skeletonAttack;
                                mana = mana - manaCost;
                                goto skeletonFight;
                            }
                            if(action2==3)
                            {
                                if(hpPots<=0)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You have no potions!\n\n";
                                    goto skeletonFight;
                                }
                                else
                                std::cout   << "You drink the potion.\n"
                                            << "+10 Health!";
                                HP = HP + 10;
                                hpPots = hpPots - 1;
                                goto skeletonFight;
                            }
                            if(action2==4)
                            {
                                if(manaPots<=0)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You have no potions!\n\n";
                                    goto skeletonFight;
                                }
                                else
                                std::cout   << "You drink the potion.\n"
                                            << "+10 Mana!";
                                mana = mana + 10;
                                manaPots = manaPots - 1;
                                goto skeletonFight;
                            }
    }
                    endTrail:
                    std::cin.get();
                    std::cout   << "You head down the rest of the path as it opens up to wide\n"
                                "farmland. Crops line up the fields and the tang of sweet root hits\n"
                                "your nostrils.\n\n";
                    std::cin.get();
                    std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                                "Peering out into the landscape, you spot a giant silouhette of a man lying down.\n"
                                "The man is next to a house. You realize that this is no man, but a giant.\n"
                                "You approach the monstrous being slowly and carefully, at this point you're probably\n"
                                "20 meters away from him. It appears he is sleeping.\n\n";
                    std::cin.get();
                    std::cout   << "What do you do?\n\n"
                                "[1] Attack him while he's sleeping\n"
                                "[2] Waken the giant\n"
                                "[3] Run\n"; 
                    std::cin    >> giantAction;

                    switch(giantAction)
                    {
                        case 1: std::cout   << "You leap forward and put all of your might into attacking\n"
                                            "the giants open throat. The earth shakes and pines roar as\n"
                                            "the giant awakens in a scream of pain. He immediately lunges at\n"
                                            "in your direction. You evade just in time to dodge his attack.\n\n"
                                            "What do you do?\n";
                                std::cin.get();
                                std::cout   << "[1] Engage\n"
                                            "[2] Run\n"; 
                                std::cin    >> giantFight;
                                giantHP = giantHP - 7;
                        if(giantFight==1)
                    {   
                        giantFight:

                        std::cout   << "\nYour HP: "    << HP << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Your Mana: " << mana << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Your Attack: " << attack << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "\nEnemy HP: " << giantHP << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "Enemy Attack: " << giantAttack  << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "\nWhat do you do?\n"
                                    "[1] Attack            [2] " << abilityname << " (" << manaCost << " Mana)" << " (" << abilitydmg << " Damage)" << std::endl;
                        std::cout   << "[3] Health Potion " << "(" << hpPots << ") " << "[4] Mana Potion " << "(" << manaPots << ")" << std::endl;
                        std::cin    >> action3;                     
                        std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
                    }
                        if(giantHP<=0)
                        {
                            if(HP<=0)
                            {
                                std::cout   << "\n\n---------- You have died! ----------\n\n";
                                std::cin.get();
                                            goto tavern;
                            }
                            std::cout   << "You have slain the mighty giant!\n"
                                        "You loot his corpse and take the spoils\n"
                                        "of battle!"
                                        "\n\n---Congratulations! You have finished the Farm Giant Hunt!---\n\n";
                                switch(classID)
                            {
                                loot:
                                loot = rand() % 3 + 1; 
                                srand(time(NULL));

                                case 1: switch(loot){
                                                    case 1: std::cout   << "---You find the Giant Slayer!---\n"
                                                                        "+9 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 9;
                                                                        goto tavern; 
                                                    case 2: std::cout   << "---You find a Steel Sword!---\n"
                                                                        "+5 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 5;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 3: std::cout   << "---You find a Bastard Sword!---\n"
                                                                        "+6 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 6;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 4: std::cout   << "---You find a Tempered Blade!---\n"
                                                                        "+7 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 7;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                case 2: switch(loot){
                                                    case 1: std::cout   << "---You find an Emerald Staff!---\n"
                                                                        "+5 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+5 Magic Damage!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 5;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 5; 
                                                                        goto tavern; 
                                                    case 2: std::cout   << "---You find an Enchanted Scepter!---\n"
                                                                        "+6 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+7 Magic Damage\n"
                                                                        "+10 Mana Cost!\n";
                                                                        manaCost = manaCost + 10;
                                                                        attack = attack + 6;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 7;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 3: std::cout   << "---You find an Studded Scepter!---\n"
                                                                        "+6 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+6 Magic Damage!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 6;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 6;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 4: std::cout   << "---You find a Ruby Staff!---\n"
                                                                        "+7 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+4 Magic Damage\n"; 
                                                                        attack = attack + 7;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 4;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                case 3: switch(loot){
                                                    case 1: std::cout   << "---You find a Broken Dagger!---\n"
                                                                        "+3 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+5 Backstab Damage!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 3;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 5; 
                                                                        goto tavern; 
                                                    case 2: std::cout   << "---You find a Shortsword!---\n"
                                                                        "+6 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+3 Backstab Damage!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 6;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 3; 
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 3: std::cout   << "---You find an Glass Knife!---\n"
                                                                        "+5 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+10 Backstab Damage!\n"; 
                                                                        attack = attack + 5;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 10;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 4: std::cout   << "---You find a Ceremonial Dagger!---\n"
                                                                        "+7 Attack!\n"
                                                                        "+6 Backstab Damage!\n";
                                                                        attack= attack + 7;
                                                                        abilitydmg = abilitydmg + 6;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                case 4: switch(loot){
                                                    case 1: std::cout   << "---You find a Cleric's Mace!---\n"
                                                                        "+5 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 5;
                                                                        goto tavern; 
                                                    case 2: std::cout   << "---You find a Warhammer!---\n"
                                                                        "+7 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 7;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 3: std::cout   << "---You find an Steel Hammer!---\n"
                                                                        "+6 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 6;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    case 4: std::cout   << "---You find a Giant's Club!---\n"
                                                                        "+10 Attack!\n";
                                                                        attack = attack + 10;
                                                                        goto tavern;
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                            if(action3==1)
                            {
                                std::cout   << "You successfully hit the giant for " << attack << std::endl;
                                std::cout   << "He strikes back for " << giantAttack << std::endl;
                                giantHP = giantHP - attack;
                                HP = HP - giantAttack;
                                goto giantFight;
                                }
                            else if(action3==2)
                            {
                                if(mana<=0)
                            {
                                std::cout << "\nYou do not have enough Mana!\n";
                                goto giantFight;
                            }
                            if(classID==1)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You successfully stun the enemy and attack it for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                    giantHP = giantHP - abilitydmg;
                                    mana = mana - manaCost;
                                    goto giantFight;
                                }
                            if(classID==4)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "The Holy Light infuses you. You successfully heal for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                    HP = HP + abilitydmg;
                                    mana = mana - manaCost;
                                    goto giantFight;
                                }
                            else
                                std::cout   << "You successfully hit the giant for " << abilitydmg << std::endl;
                                std::cout   << "It strikes back for " << giantAttack << std::endl;
                                giantHP = giantHP - abilitydmg;
                                HP = HP - giantAttack;
                                mana = mana - manaCost;
                                goto giantFight;
                            }
                            else if(action3==3)
                            {
                                if(hpPots<=0)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You have no potions!\n\n";
                                    goto giantFight;
                                }
                                else 
                                std::cout   << "You drink the potion.\n"
                                            "+10 Health!";
                                HP = HP + 10;
                                hpPots = hpPots - 1;
                                goto giantFight;
                            }
                            else if(action3==4)
                            {
                                if(manaPots<=0)
                                {
                                    std::cout   << "You have no potions!\n\n";
                                    goto giantFight;
                                }
                                else
                                std::cout   << "You drink the potion.\n"
                                            "+10 Mana!";
                                mana = mana + 10;
                                manaPots = manaPots - 1;
                                goto giantFight;
                            }
                            else                                
                            {
                                std::cout   << "You take the cowards way out and run.\n";
                                goto tavern;
                            }
                    }                               
                        case 2:     
                                std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                                            "You quietly approach the giant and awaken him from his slumber\n"
                                            "He quickly gets to his feet and assumes a defensive posture.\n"
                                            "After looking at his surroundings, the giant questions,\n\n"
                                            "'Who dares awaken me?!\n\n";
                                std::cin.get();
                                std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                                            "You introduce yourself, and inform him of the problem of the nearby villagers.\n"
                                            "After the conflict is talked about, he offers a compromise.\n\n"
                                            "'If you, measly man can answer my riddle, I shall return to where\n"
                                            "I came from and leave this place in peace.'\n"
                                            "The giant shifts where he stands and prepares his riddle.\n\n";
                                std::cin.get();
                                std::cout   << "---------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                                            "I have a heart that never beats, I have a home but I never sleep\n"
                                            "I can take a mans house and build anothers, And I love to play games\n"
                                            "with my many brothers. A King among fools.\n\n"
                                            "What am I?\n\n"
                                            "[1] A Jester\n"
                                            "[2] King of Hearts\n"
                                            "[3] A Trickster\n"
                                            "[4] -Do not answer-\n";
                                std::cin    >> riddleAnswer; 
                                    if(riddleAnswer==2)
                                    {
                                        std::cout   << "You have correctly answered my riddle. I shall leave in peace\n"
                                                    "You return on the path you walked and head back to the tavern.\n";
                                        std::cin.get();
                                        std::cout   << "\n\n---Congratulations! You have finished the Farm Giant Hunt!---\n\n";
                                                    goto loot;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        std::cout   << "You have incorrectly answered my riddle, prepare to die puny man!\n";
                                                    goto giantFight;
                                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot to do ;)

Three main problems:

1. `main()` large as big as blue whale! 
   Try to divide it to smaller functions - you can start with making every `case` of top-level `swich` a separate function! (It will be easy then to introduce classes and make code objective)
2. Early declarations of variables. Try to declarate it as late as possible - for example just before first assigment of the value.
3. Very mysterious variable names. What is `class1`? I realized it only after reading content of first `cout`. But what if this content will be in some foreign langue? Name variables more descriptively... even too descriptively! When you will be very experienced programmer, you will know how to make good names. But now, I recommend you to create too long and too descriptive variable names.

And the home excercise for you - think about how can you avoid `goto` statements!
`goto` itselves are not pure evil. But the usage of them very often is a sign that somewhere in the code, there is something very bad.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how you'd take things out of main and sort them out better?

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure this quite a bit. In particular, I think nearly all the data about players and NPCs should go in an external data file (or maybe more than one). Likewise, the map should be in a data file. Depending on how you want things to work you can create a semi-random game by creating a game file that has (for example) various NPCs and other objects at various nodes in the map.

The program itself becomes a small engine that can interpret those data files, and react to the player's input. But (and this is important, IMO) nearly nothing but the engine really belongs in the program proper. By switching out the data files, you should (for example) be able to change it from a game of a cave with goblins and dragons into a game of a castle with sprites and pixies.

Comment: How would this look like in code?